# Android Load File From Res Error

Tags: android, file, file-io

I'm trying to load a text file from res/raw. I've looked at several code snippets and tried implementing a few ways but none seem to work for me. The code I currently am trying to get to work is this

```
TextView helloTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hellotxt);
        helloTxt.setText(readTxt());
    }

    private String readTxt() {

     InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.hello);

     ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

     int i;
     try {
         i = inputStream.read();
         while (i != -1) {
             byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
             i = inputStream.read();
         }
         inputStream.close();
     }
     catch (IOException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

     return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
```

But it suffers from te same problem as all the others do.

a) `(TextView)findViewById(R.id.hellotxt);` says it depreciated and Eclipses recommends Migrating code.

b) `getResources()` isn't recognized and just suggests I add a method called getResources().

Initially I wanted to use assets folder but got the same error as b) but with getAssets().

This is a seperate class file I'm implementing this is called `public class PassGen{}` with one method at the moment called `public String returnPass(){}`

Comment: Above code is working on Android 2.3.3.

Comment: It does if in a Activity class but not in a seperate add-on class

Comment: What do you mean by ad-on class

Comment: A class that does not extend activity. Read bottom part of post and comment below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions getAssets and getResources should be called from a Context.

If you call it from within an Activity class it doesn't need a prefix, but otherwise you'd need to pass the context to the class that needs the functions and call e.g. context.getAssets().

Comment: So what would a context be? I've looked up the Android developers site but it just says it returns the abstract for AssetManager

Comment: Context documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html
Just passing 'this' from the Activity class should work.

Answer (score 1):

Activity Class:

```
public class ReadFileActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Read read = new Read(getApplicationContext());

    TextView helloTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hellotxt);
    helloTxt.setText(read.readTxt());
}
}
```

Read Class:

```
public class Read {

Context ctx;

public Read(Context applicationContext) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.ctx = applicationContext;
}


public String readTxt() {

    InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.hello);

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int i;
    try {
        i = inputStream.read();
        while (i != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
            i = inputStream.read();
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
}
}
```